# esp8266 RTOS blink example doesn't work

Tags: esp8266

I have a problem with the RTOS firmware on the esp8266 (I have a esp12e), after flashing the firmware, reading from uart, it keeps stuck with those lines:

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,0)
load 0x40100000, len 31584, room 16
tail 0
chksum 0x24
load 0x3ffe8000, len 944, room 8
tail 8
chksum 0x9e
load 0x3ffe83b0, len 1080, room 0
tail 8
chksum 0x60
csum 0x60
```

Now I will explain my HW setup:

```
GPIO15 -> Gnd
EN -> Vcc
GPIO0 -> Gnd (when flashing)
GPIO0 -> Vcc (normal mode)
```

For the toolchain I've followed this tutorial and it works well:
http://microcontrollerkits.blogspot.it/2015/12/esp8266-eclipse-development.html

Then I started doing my RTOS blink example, I post my user_main.c code here:

```
#include "esp_common.h"
#include "gpio.h"

void task2(void *pvParameters)
{
    printf("Hello, welcome to client!\r\n");
    while(1)
    {
    // Delay and turn on
    vTaskDelay (300/portTICK_RATE_MS);
        GPIO_OUTPUT_SET (5, 1);

    // Delay and LED off
        vTaskDelay (300/portTICK_RATE_MS);
        GPIO_OUTPUT_SET (5, 0);
    }
}

/******************************************************************************
 * FunctionName : user_rf_cal_sector_set
 * Description  : SDK just reversed 4 sectors, used for rf init data and paramters.
 *                We add this function to force users to set rf cal sector, since
 *                we don't know which sector is free in user's application.
 *                sector map for last several sectors : ABCCC
 *                A : rf cal
 *                B : rf init data
 *                C : sdk parameters
 * Parameters   : none
 * Returns      : rf cal sector
*******************************************************************************/
uint32 user_rf_cal_sector_set(void)
{
    flash_size_map size_map = system_get_flash_size_map();
    uint32 rf_cal_sec = 0;

    switch (size_map) {
        case FLASH_SIZE_4M_MAP_256_256:
            rf_cal_sec = 128 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_8M_MAP_512_512:
            rf_cal_sec = 256 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_512_512:
        case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 512 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_512_512:
        case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 1024 - 5;
            break;

        default:
            rf_cal_sec = 0;
            break;
    }

    return rf_cal_sec;
}

/******************************************************************************
 * FunctionName : user_init
 * Description  : entry of user application, init user function here
 * Parameters   : none
 * Returns      : none
*******************************************************************************/
void user_init(void)
{
    uart_init_new();

    printf("SDK version:%s\n", system_get_sdk_version());

    // Config pin as GPIO5
    PIN_FUNC_SELECT (PERIPHS_IO_MUX_GPIO5_U, FUNC_GPIO5);

    xTaskCreate(task2, "tsk2", 256, NULL, 2, NULL);
}
```

I also post the flash command, the first executed one time, the second every time I modify the code:

```
c:/Espressif/utils/ESP8266/esptool.exe -p COM3 write_flash -ff 40m -fm qio -fs 32m 0x3FC000 c:/Espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/bin/esp_init_data_default.bin 0x3FE000 c:/Espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/bin/blank.bin 0x7E000 c:/Espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/bin/blank.bin

c:/Espressif/utils/ESP8266/esptool.exe -p COM3 -b 256000 write_flash -ff 40m -fm qio -fs 32m 0x00000 firmware/eagle.flash.bin 0x40000 firmware/eagle.irom0text.bin
```

There is something wrong? I really don't understand why it doesn't work.
When I try the NON-OS example they works very well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. This issue is caused by the incorrect address of the eagle.irom0text.bin .

So I changed the address of the eagle.irom0text.bin from 0x40000 (0x10000) to 0x20000 and it worked well for me.

[RTOS SDK version: 1.4.2(f57d61a)]

The correct flash codes in the common_rtos.mk (ESP-12E)

for flashinit

```
flashinit:
$(vecho) "Flash init data default and blank data."
$(ESPTOOL) -p $(ESPPORT) write_flash $(flashimageoptions) 0x3fc000 $(SDK_BASE)/bin/esp_init_data_default.bin
$(ESPTOOL) -p $(ESPPORT) write_flash $(flashimageoptions) 0x3fe000 $(SDK_BASE)/bin/blank.bin
```

for flash:

```
flash: all
#ifeq ($(app), 0) 
$(ESPTOOL) -p $(ESPPORT) -b $(ESPBAUD) write_flash $(flashimageoptions) 0x00000 $(FW_BASE)/eagle.flash.bin 0x20000 $(FW_BASE)/eagle.irom0text.bin
else
ifeq ($(boot), none)
$(ESPTOOL) -p $(ESPPORT) -b $(ESPBAUD) write_flash $(flashimageoptions) 0x00000 $(FW_BASE)/eagle.flash.bin 0x20000 $(FW_BASE)/eagle.irom0text.bin
else
$(ESPTOOL) -p $(ESPPORT) -b $(ESPBAUD) write_flash $(flashimageoptions) $(addr) $(FW_BASE)/upgrade/$(BIN_NAME).bin
endif
endif
```

Comment: I will try your solution as soon as possible and then I will accept your answer!